# Deploy a Rails app with elasticsearch gem to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, deployment, elasticsearch

I am trying to deploy a local version of my Rails app with Elasticsearch to AWS Beanstalk and I am not quite sure how to do it.

I know when I brew installed Elasticsearch locally it setup a server (on port 9200) to handle requests.

I EB deployed my branch to my EC2 and when I go to the site it just says something is wrong.

I have a feeling it is because I do not have Elasticsearch running on AWS. I am pretty new to AWS and not quite sure what to do. Should I be setting up another EC2 that runs Elasticsearch?

If so, how should I go about doing it and how do I connect that instance of Elasticsearch so it communicates with my rails app?

Comment: what is the command you are using to run the app in terminal?

Comment: Locally? I followed the brew install elasticsearch instructions after brew installing java. 

To push it to AWS, I selected to which instance I wanted to push to and then in my console (on the branch I want to push up to aws) I typed ED deploy

Comment: Check the errors in /var/log/puma/puma.log

Comment: Don't have that file/folder in AWS

Comment: Check if you have properly set your production secret key base and Try this link- it may help..http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Comment: I had it successfully deployed before, just when I added elasticsearch to my local it broke when I tried to deploy.

Comment: Try to find out the error log file, there you can find what's the actual error.

Comment: amazon has Amazon Elasticsearch Service, so you can create elasticsearch domain there and set elasticsearch host url in your rails app to the endpoint from AES